# Is there a source in Torah that a soul chooses his parents before being born?

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul

Many years ago, I read in a Jewish book that a soul chooses his parents before being born, but I cannot remember the name of the book.  Is there an authentic Torah source that confirms this?  Thank you.

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/425923/jewish/Did-You-Ask-to-Be-Born.htm makes a similar claim, but I don't know if they have any substantial source (though it does say at the bottom that he bases what he says on the Lubavitcher Rebbe). And there are reasons to say why it doesn't really make sense, like people being born into literally the worst circumstances (you have access to the news right?).

Comment: Similar.  (Dupe?)  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92954/5