# Does the Neshama (soul) choose the body?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, pregnancy-birth, soul

I think i might have read in various places i just can't find where  that the neshama chooses the body based on the life missions that it needs to accomplish so it chooses the most suitable conditions in order for the soul to elevate itself.

Is there a source for this or am i getting this all wrong?

Comment: Similar.  Dupe?  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78259/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blessing we say in the morning, אלק״י נשמה שנתת בי says clearly the opposite. G-d is the one who determines which body the Neshamah enters.

> My G-d, the soul which you placed in me is pure. You created it, You formed it and You blew it into me...

Comment: Interestingly, we call the body בי but your Neshome שלי. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @AlBerko I’m not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I would expect it to be the other way around - "אלקי, נתת אותי בתוך גופי", as I am the Neshome, ain't I?

Comment: @AlBerko Actually, you are both body and soul. When we talk about G-d choosing us (כי בנו בחרת), we are referring to the Jewish body, not the soul. And if you look at the language of the blessing, the one talking is the body.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to use "comment" yet, please take this answer as a comment.

From your question, it seems you look at Neshama and Body 2 different "things" or objects.  Yet, my understanding to Judaism, all is ONE.  Adonai Echad.  Could it possible body and spirit (besides, there is a mind as human being) is one, not two.

If there are 2, it means Hashem puts a Neshama into a body which is similar with your question: Neshama chooses the body.

If they are ONE, could it possible the quality of Neshama makes and forms the body? So, we say we can tell one from one's eyes, since eyes are the window of soul.?

Just a comment.